# Bootstrap inline button dropdown within <p> jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently I have a jumbotron setup with some paragraph text, and I would like to stick a button dropdown inline with the text.

**Dropdown button**

```
<span class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Button... <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Opt 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Opt 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

**Jumbotron**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
  <p>Welcome</p>
  <p>Another paragraph
   <!-- dropdown is here -->
  </p>
</div> <!-- jumbotron -->
```

If the dropdown is within the `<p>` tag, it does not "dropdown" (but renders). If it is outside of the `<p>` tag it functions fine, but I would like it to be inline with the text and need the text to be in the `<p>` tag to get the style. Any ideas?

Things to note -- If I replace the `<span>` tags with `<div>` tags, it will work fine within the `<p>` tags, but won't be inline.

---

**Solution**

Added `class="pull-left"` on the `<p>` tag to get it inline (from Esotericist's answer)

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
  <p>Welcome</p>
  <p class="pull-left">Another paragraph</p>
   <!-- dropdown is here -->

</div> <!-- jumbotron -->
```

Comment: have you tried `pull-right` or `pull-left` ?

Comment: @Esotericist on the dropdown?

Comment: yeah, `class="btn-group pull-right"` will push it inline, if I am understanding you correctly? (edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it inline then you need to use pull-left and pull-right, see here for an example:

http://www.bootply.com/T2wgdlzhZf

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Pretty much, I'll except your answer and update showing what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: The link is broken!